# Dart DateTime not showing right time

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I am using flutter to build an app, so therefore I am also using dart. I need to use the DateTime class for a calendar.

When I execute the following line of code:
`print(DateTime.now())`
It prints:
`2022-12-29 15:27:11.147472`

I executed this code on 2023-01-04 and I executed the code at about 3:03 pm.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the date of device you run your flutter code correct?

Comment: Yeah on my mac the date is correct in the top right.

Comment: Are you using a simulator?

Comment: Haha I just realized that's the issue. The time on the simulator is wrong so that's why it showed the different date. Thank you so much. I wasted at least an hour on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the simulator that I was running the program on had the wrong date so it made the app show the wrong date as well.

Thank you to Soliev for helping me with the issue!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the device's system clock. Make sure that the device's system clock is set to the correct date and time.

There might be a problem with the device's time zone settings. Make sure that the device's time zone settings are correct.

There might be a problem with the app's code. Double-check the code to make sure that there are no errors or bugs that could be causing the incorrect date and time to be returned